# Copy a row into the next row and update the content in the new row using gspread python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a JSON file and I am looking forward to put this file content into the Google sheet after parsing it. I am using gspread for Python to interact with the Google Sheets programmatically. The format of the data in the sheet contains some columns with checkboxes, which can either be ticked or not (based on TRUE and FALSE values), some simple entries like name and contact number plus some dropdowns as well.

The content in the json is straight forward and easy to parse, so the approach I am using is to keep the very first row as a default row in my sheet and use it as a template for all of the data that is supposed to be ingested in to the sheet.

The template row has empty checkboxes and empty dropdowns by default so while processing my records I am trying to make a copy of this template row for every new index and update the content in that index based on json parsed record data. I am having difficulty in copying exactly the same content of the earlier row as I want checkboxes and dropdowns to be exist for every new row entry and update the values according to the input values.

For example: my Google sheet contains the industry names as column names with default checkboxes set as unchecked, if my processed record contain an interest to any of this industry then I need to make that checkbox value to be ticked.

This approach of making a copy of previous row might not be the ideal one but I am open for any suggestions. I have info about column values to be TRUE or FALSE but either it is programmatically possible to map them into a checkbox or not?

**Note:** I know Google App Script makes it easy to manage the content with the sheets but I want to achieve this using gspread as for future reference I will be looking forward to pull data from other sheets and parsing the data for this new sheet.

Sample Record

```
records = [{
    "timestamp": "2023-08-14 12:45:00.127784",
    "legacyID": "CRM01",
    "firstName": "David",
    "lastName": "Richards",
    "preferredName": "",
    "preferredPronouns": "",
    "interests": [
        "Semiconductors"
    ],
    "eligibility": [],
    "lead": {
        "status": "Subscribed",
        "source": "",
        "sourcePath": "",
        "value": "",
        "reliability": "",
        "onBoardDate": "",
        "lastContactDate": "",
        "offBoardDate": ""
    },
    "segmentation": {
        "organisation": "M UK Limited"
        
    },
    "audit": {
        "createdDate": "2023-08-14 12:45:00.128195",
        "createdBy": "Admin",
        "lastModifiedDate": "",
        "lastModifiedBy": "",
        "deletedDate": None,
        "deletedBy": None,
        "deleteRequestedBy": None,
        "auditor_email": ""
    },
    "comments": []
}]

start_index = 7

template_row = worksheet2.row_values(start_index)

for idx, record in enumerate(records, start_index + 1):
    new_row_index = start_index + 1
    worksheet2.insert_row(template_row, index=new_row_index)
    updated_row = template_row.copy()
    checkbox_columns = [
    "FinTech", "MedTech", "Advanced Manufacturing", "Creative", "Net Zero",
    "Semiconductors", "Digital", "Business", "Software Development",
    "Data Science", "Cyber Security", "Games Development", "Repair",
    "Business Development", "Entrepreneurship/Intrapreneurship",
    "Mental Health", "Skills Academies", "Professional & Upskilling",
    "Apprenticeships"
]

  interests_arr = record['interests']

  for column_name in checkbox_columns:
      if column_name in interests_arr:
         updated_row[worksheet2.find(column_name).col - 1] = "TRUE"
      else:
         updated_row[worksheet2.find(column_name).col - 1] = "FALSE"
   
   worksheet2.update(updated_row, index=idx)
```

In the sample record, the interests column stores the id for one of the industry names and I am getting the industry name by querying it from DB and I want the checkbox to be ticked for the relevant industry name.

[image]

Above is the screenshot of the spreadsheet where data is getting in. I am not able to convert these TRUE and FALSE values to be converted into the checkboxes programmatically. The first row is the default template row which I want to use.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result. `records` is your expected sample input value? If my understanding is correct, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situation you expect using the sample input value? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I have updated my question now.  Yes "records" is the sample input and the expected output is to enter the input content into a Google worksheet this sheet had some columns with checkboxes that I want to be checked or not based on my records values. sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Thank you for replying. From my comment, I guess that your added image is the sample output situation using your sample value of `records`. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your added image. But, I would like to try to correctly understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I apologize that I cannot resolve your question soon.

Comment: Your Python script isn't fully reproducible due to the line `result = tags_collection.find_one({"_id": objInstance})`, where the `tags_collection` data does not exist. Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ensure that your sample Python script can be easily reproduced. Thank you.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set TRUE or FALSE as the checkbox when the values of `interests` in your values of `records` are included in the header title of `checkbox_columns`.
- You want to achieve this using gspread.

When I saw your showing script, `update` and `find` are used in loops. In this case, the process cost becomes high. And also, when Sheets API is used in a loop, an error related to the continuous requests might occur. I'm worried about this.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, by using the batchUpdate method, Sheets API is used only one time for writing values.

#### Sample script:

```py
import gspread

client = ### Please use your client for gspread

spreadsheet_key = "###" # Please set Spreadsheet ID.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key)
worksheet2 = spreadsheet.worksheet("Sheet1") # Please set sheet name.

# This is a simple sample value including "interests" property for testing this script.
records = [
    {"interests": ["Semiconductors", "Repair"]},
    {"interests": []},
    {"interests": ["MedTech", "Digital"]},
    {"interests": ["Entrepreneurship/Intrapreneurship", "Data Science", "Apprenticeships"]},
]

# This is from your showing script.
checkbox_columns = [
    "FinTech", "MedTech", "Advanced Manufacturing", "Creative", "Net Zero",
    "Semiconductors", "Digital", "Business", "Software Development",
    "Data Science", "Cyber Security", "Games Development", "Repair",
    "Business Development", "Entrepreneurship/Intrapreneurship",
    "Mental Health", "Skills Academies", "Professional & Upskilling",
    "Apprenticeships"
]
start_index = 7  # This is from your showing script.

header_len = len(checkbox_columns)
dst_values = []
for e in records:
    if "interests" in e:
        interests = e.get("interests", [])
        if interests == []:
            dst_values.append(
                {"values": [{
                    "dataValidation": {"condition": {"type": "BOOLEAN"}},
                    "userEnteredValue": {"boolValue": False}
                } for _ in range(header_len)]}
            )
        else:
            values = []
            for h in checkbox_columns:
                values.append({
                    "dataValidation": {"condition": {"type": "BOOLEAN"}},
                    "userEnteredValue": {"boolValue": h in interests}
                })
            dst_values.append({"values": values})

if dst_values != []:
    requests = [{
        "updateCells": {
            "range": {"sheetId": worksheet2.id, "startRowIndex": start_index, "startColumnIndex": 0},
            "rows": dst_values,
            "fields": "dataValidation,userEnteredValue"
        }
    }]

    # Request Sheets API.
    spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": requests})
```

- Please modify this script for your actual situation.
- In this sample script, the checkboxes are directly created using Sheets API. By this, the template row is not required to be used.

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)